# Why is expectation of lim inf enough to show sequence does not diverge

Tags: probability, analysis

Given $$E(\lim_n \inf \left| X_n \right|)\leq K <\infty$$ why are we able to say $$P(\left| X_n \right|\to \infty)=0?$$

I don't see how this follows.

Comment: Is the only way using Markov's inequality?

$$P(\lim_n \inf \left|X_n\right| > M) \leq E(\lim_n \inf \left|X_n\right|)/M?$$

I just don't see how that tells us anything about $\lim_n \left| X_n \right|$ though.

Comment: It doesn't tell you anything about $\lim_n |X_n|$, which needn't even exist under these assumptions, but the event $|X_n| \to \infty$ is contained in the event $\liminf_n |X_n|>M$ for all $M>0$.

Comment: So I was on the right track is what you're saying?

Comment: Yep; the left side of your inequality is bigger than the thing you want to bound (which no longer depends on $M$), so sending $M \to \infty$ on the right side of your inequality gives the desired result.

Comment: Is there another way to do this besides Markov's? I feel like this should be more obvious to show because if I needed Markov's I would think the author would say so.

Comment: Well, if $|X_n(\omega)| \to \infty$ then $\liminf_n |X_n(\omega)|=\infty$. So if the set of such $\omega$s has positive probability, then the expectation that was given at the top would be infinite. But you were told it was finite...

Comment: Mmm aren't there cases where the random variable diverges but has finite expectation though? For example, let $X_n$ be $0$ everywhere except take on $n^2$ on the interval $[0,1/n]$...$EX_n = n \to \infty$.

Comment: But then $X_n(\omega) \to 0$ for each fixed $\omega$, so $X_n$ never actually blows up. (This is one of those times where it can be useful to actually write out everything in terms of $\omega$s rather than suppressing the dependence on $\omega$.)

Comment: OH! I see. Thanks!